# BBEdit: Text Filter cannot handle Umlauts (ä,ü,ö)

Tags: configuration, bbedit

The target is: format text as columns.

I created the following text filter in BBEdit 11.6.4 (latest version):

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 's/   */ ¶/g' | column -s '¶' -t
```

I applied it to the following text (UTF-8 document):

```
zot foo   bär   pak
lorem sit   ipsum   doloret
```

Expected result:

```
zot foo     bär     pak
lorem sit   ipsum   doloret
```

Real result:

```
zot foo     bär      pak
lorem sit   ipsum   doloret
```

As soon as an umlaut exists in the text, the number of inserted blanks are not correct.
It seems the reg ex machine of BBEdit treats umlauts in a special way.

Do you know a solution?

Note:
The text filter works fine for any text without umlauts.

Answer (score 0):

I get a solution in the "BBEdit Google Groups":

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bbedit/yuLz48rIyoc

Seems to be a bug in BBEdit.